# How to trigger the minimal task on Gradle to run apt plugin

Tags: android, gradle, annotations, annotation-processing, android-apt

I'm creating a compile-time annotation processor to generate some code on Android.

To trigger the annotation processor I'm using the `android-apt` plugin from hvisser https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/overview

At the moment, on every change I do on my `Processor extends AbstractProcessor` I have to run a full `/.gradlew clean build` to see the results, and that is kinda of a slow process, even for a tiny sample project.

So my question, is there any of the `gradlew tasks` I could use to trigger the annotation processor?

The output from my current `./gradlew tasks` is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Android tasks
-------------
androidDependencies - Displays the Android dependencies of the project.
signingReport - Displays the signing info for each variant.

Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
assembleDebug - Assembles all Debug builds.
assembleDebugAndroidTest - Assembles the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
assembleRelease - Assembles all Release builds.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
classes - Assembles classes 'main'.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
compileDebugAndroidTestSources
compileDebugSources
compileDebugUnitTestSources
compileReleaseSources
compileReleaseUnitTestSources
jar - Assembles a jar archive containing the main classes.
mockableAndroidJar - Creates a version of android.jar that's suitable for unit tests.
testClasses - Assembles classes 'test'.

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build. [incubating]
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files. [incubating]

Documentation tasks
-------------------
javadoc - Generates Javadoc API documentation for the main source code.

Help tasks
----------
components - Displays the components produced by root project 'Decorator'. [incubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'Decorator'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'Decorator'.
help - Displays a help message.
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'Decorator'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'Decorator'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'Decorator' (some of the displayed tasks may belong to subprojects).

Install tasks
-------------
installDebug - Installs the Debug build.
installDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
uninstallAll - Uninstall all applications.
uninstallDebug - Uninstalls the Debug build.
uninstallDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
uninstallRelease - Uninstalls the Release build.

Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
connectedAndroidTest - Installs and runs instrumentation tests for all flavors on connected devices.
connectedAndroidTestDebug - Installs and runs the tests for Debug build on connected devices.
connectedCheck - Runs all device checks on currently connected devices.
deviceAndroidTest - Installs and runs instrumentation tests using all Device Providers.
deviceCheck - Runs all device checks using Device Providers and Test Servers.
lint - Runs lint on all variants.
lintDebug - Runs lint on the Debug build.
lintRelease - Runs lint on the Release build.
test - Runs the unit tests.
testDebug - Run unit tests for the debug build.
testRelease - Run unit tests for the release build.

Other tasks
-----------
jarDebugClasses
jarReleaseClasses
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out any solution for this?

Comment: @Abdullah no. I was running assembleDebug, but it would be great to have something better

Answer (score 1):

Source generation happens when you compile. So running `gradlew cleanCompileDebugSources compileDebugSources` is what you need. This is the same was what Android Studio is running when you `make` your project from the `build` menu.

If you are developing your annotation processor as part of your project, you can use the `processor` option in `android-apt` without needing to package your processor project. This is assuming you have your processor module as a `apt project(':myprocessor')` dependency (`compile` will also work).

```
apt {
    processor "my.class.name"
}
```