# What task to run to re-create Dagger 2 injection files

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

When I make changes to Dagger 2 components, I'd like it to rebuild the injection classes. But I don't want to run a whole project Rebuild because that takes 5 minutes, even with the gradle daemon.

In some cases it automatically rebuilds, but in other cases it doesn't.

What gradle task can I run to just re-create the Dagger 2 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate the source files by running the `apt` plugin. This happens while compiling your sources. Use `gradlew compileDebugSources` to trigger the compilation or use *Make Project* in your IDE.

If you want to check the [sources](https://github.com/Jimdo/gradle-apt-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/jimdo/gradle/AptPlugin.groovy#L72), you can see that it attaches itself to the `javaCompile` tasks.

Also see [How to trigger the minimal task on Gradle to run apt plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539646/how-to-trigger-the-minimal-task-on-gradle-to-run-apt-plugin).